# QMediaPlayer::metaData() can't get cover of mp3

Tags: qt, metadata, qmediaplayer

I set mp3 media with cover to `QMediaPlayer`, I call `QMediaPlayer::isMetaDataAvailable()` and it returns true, then I call `QMediaPlayer::availableMetaData()`, and it returns this:

```
("Author", "AverageLevel", "Description", "PeakValue", "Title", "WM/AlbumArtist", "WM/AlbumTitle", "WM/Composer", "WM/ContentGroupDescription", "WM/Genre", "WM/Picture", "WM/Track", "WM/TrackNumber", "WM/Year")
```

And if I call for example `QMediaPlayer::metaData(QMediaMetaData::Title).toString()` it returns correct title.
But for some reason all of above return nothing but emptiness:

```
qDebug()<< player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::CoverArtImage).toString();
qDebug()<< player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::CoverArtUrlLarge).toString();
qDebug()<< player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::CoverArtUrlLarge).toString();
qDebug()<< player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::CoverArtUrlSmall).toString();
qDebug()<< player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::PosterImage).toString();
qDebug()<< player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::PosterUrl).toString();
```

I don't get why. Could anybody give me any suggestions?

Comment: `CoverArtImage` and `PosterImage` return `QImage`. I am not sure sure you can cast the variant to string. Did you try `player->metdata("WM/Picture")` ? Then `variant.value<QImage>()` to get the actual image from the variant?

Comment: `player->metaData("WM/Picture").value<QImage>().isNull()` returns true.. @Kikohs

Comment: did you check the variant before casting it to qimage?

Comment: output of that `QVariant` looks like this: `QVariant(Invalid)` @Kikohs

Comment: This is so strange. Even though it returns `"WM/Picture"` as a part of the `QMediaPlayer::availableMetaData()`, when I try `QMediaPlayer::metaData("WM/Picture").isValid()` it returns false, and `QMediaPlayer::metaData("WM/Picture").isNull();` returns true..